# C# Enum deserialization with Json.Net: Error converting value to type

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm using Json.NET to serialize/deserialize some JSON APIs.

The API response have some integer values that map to an Enum defined in the application.

The enum is like this:

```c#
public enum MyEnum
{
    Type1,
    Type2,
    Type3
}
```

and the JSON API response has the following:

```json
{
    "Name": "abc",
    "MyEnumValue":"Type1"
}
```

sometimes the API returns a value for the MyEnumValue field that's not defined in my enum, like this:

```json
{
    "Name": "abc",
    "MyEnumValue":"Type4"
}
```

That throws an exception:

> **Error converting value "Type4" to type 'MyEnum'**

Is there a way to handle this error by assigning a default value or something to avoid the application crash?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `DefaultValue` for the property http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm

Comment: Thanks, I tried but still the exception is thrown

Comment: I know this is an old question, but 8 years later here I am perplexed with the same problem.  
The approsch I used was using an attribute in the class model.
If using Json.Net

```public class SampleEntity
{
    [JsonProperty("error")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public ErrorCode Error { get; set; }
}```
or..... if using System.Text.Json

```public class SampleEntity
{
    [JsonProperty("error")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public ErrorCode Error { get; set; }
}```

https://www.bytefish.de/blog/enums_json_net.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's say we have the following json string:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "abc",
        "MyEnumValue": "Type1"
    },
    {
        "Name": "abcd",
        "MyEnumValue": "Type2"
    },
    {
        "Name": "abcde",
        "MyEnumValue": "Type3"
    }    ,
    {
        "Name": "abcdef",
        "MyEnumValue": "Type4"
    }
]
```

and the following class and enum:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MyEnum MyEnumValue { get; set; }
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    Type1,
    Type2,
    Type3
}
```

As it can be noticed, the json string array contains item (the last one), that cannot be correctly mapped to the `MyEnum`. To avoid deserialization errors you can use the following code snippet:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{         
    var serializationSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Error = HandleDeserializationError
    };

    var lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(jsonStr, serializationSettings);
}

public static void HandleDeserializationError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs errorArgs)
{
    errorArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
    var currentObj = errorArgs.CurrentObject as MyClass;

    if (currentObj == null) return;
    currentObj.MyEnumValue = MyEnum.Type2;            
}
```

where the `jsonStr` variable is the posted json string above. In the above code sample, if `MyEnumValue` cannot be correctly interpreted, it is set to a default value of `Type2`.

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WKd2Lt

Comment: Yikes, how is assigning a default value a solution? Maybe Type5 or Type6 or TypeX cannot be equated to Type2? The point is the client cannot anticipate what the server might return in future, so assuming you can assign a default value is dangerous.

Answer (score 13):

The only way I see it, you should write your own converter. But half of work is already done in class `StringEnumConverter`. We can override only `ReadJson` method

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string json = @"{
                'Name': 'abc',
                'Type':'Type4'
            }";

        // uncomment this if you want to use default value other then default enum first value
        //var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        //settings.Converters.Add(new FooTypeEnumConverter { DefaultValue = FooType.Type3 });

        //var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json, settings);

        var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public FooType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum FooType
{
    Type1,
    Type2,
    Type3
}

public class FooTypeEnumConverter : StringEnumConverter
{
    public FooType DefaultValue { get; set; }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
        }
        catch (JsonSerializationException)
        {
            return DefaultValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that can be another alternative solution

Answer (score 6):

An alternative, if you don't want to create a custom converter, is to map it to a private string field in your DTO and then use Enum.TryParse in that field's property getter:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("MyEnumValue")]
    private string myEnumValue;

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public MyEnum MyEnumValue 
    { 
        get
        {
            MyEnum outputValue = MyEnum.Default;
            Enum.TryParse(myEnumValue, out outputValue);
            return outputValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also look into this problem,

[json with Enum DisplayName or EnumMember Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62150650/7403086)