# Deserializing an enum with a default value with Newtonsoft.JSON

Tags: c#, serialization, enums, json.net, default

I have a json string like so

```
{
  'EnumValue': 'Foo'
}
```

I'm deserializing this value to a class with an enum which has the possible values `Bar` and `Baz`.
Since `"Foo"` is not included in this enum, converting this string to a class instance with Newtonsofts JsonConverter throws an error.
Is there any way I can include a default value in my enum that catches all arbitrary values?
The code can be found in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CTMCGF).

Comment: I think this answer will help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651523/c-sharp-enum-deserialization-with-json-net-error-converting-value-to-type

Comment: @ejwill Yes, that was what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from [how Newtonsoft parses enums](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/EnumUtils.cs#L258), it is not possible.

You can try to add a string property and parse it in a get property ([Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xKzF1j)) :

```
public SampleEnum EnumRealValue {
    get {
        if(Enum.TryParse<SampleEnum>(EnumValue, out SampleEnum result)) {
            return result;
        } else {
            return default(SampleEnum);
        }
    }
}
public string EnumValue {get; set;}
```